# Why do my Ubuntu 22.04 Hyper-V virtual machines show two network adapters by default?

Tags: networking, hyper-v, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-22.04

[image: Hyper-V + Ubuntu Server 22.04]

Can anyone help me understand why Ubuntu is showing two network interfaces? I've only added one to the Hyper-V VM settings. However, I am using SR-IOV (if that is anyway related to this question).

I'd like to assign a static IP to most my VM's, but this is causing me confusion and issues when trying to adjust netplan.

I have this VM assigned to a Hyper-V virtual switch. The switch adapter has been assigned a static IP on the host Windows Server 2022 hypervisor.

Update 1
[image: ip link]

Update 2
The second adapter is a result of my enabling SR-IOV. However, when I enable this for Windows VMs, they don't create multiple adapters (at least not visibly in Network Connections). I'm not sure if a second hidden adapter is created. My understanding of SR-IOV is limited; can anyone explain why Ubuntu creates this second interface with SR-IOV enabled?

Comment: Can you show what `ip link` says about them? At first glance, it looks like one adapter with an altname, which the Ubuntu installer _somehow_ manages to confuse with two separate adapters.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I went ahead with the installation. This time I've tried just using a dhcp reservation in the Ubiquiti interface. Ubuntu picked up the fixed ip (for both adapters). e.g. 192.168.3.10
However, the enP339.. interface will not work properly so I took it down. With it enabled, I can't ping my local network.

Comment: Without the DHCP reservation, each Ubuntu network adapter would take it's own unique IP. In this case, both network adapters work. But I don't really have any need for this second interface, but I want to understand why it's even there. I feel like I'm not grasping something important. I'll try disabling SR-IOV and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Turns out it is actually related to SR-IOV. Disabling this on the VM removed the "pcie ethernet" enP33973s1 interface. Now it only shows eth0 when calling networkctl.

Comment: I have an Ubuntu 22 guest in Hyper-V and it is externally accessible from Outside. I do the same thing with a Kali guest in Hyper-V.   DHCP Reservation is not needed.  Just set up the proper network type in the Hyper-V Network Manager and then enable this network type in the Hyper-V guest.   Just read the Hyper-V documentation and search for the bits to fill in your knowledge. Works here.